# PDF to XPS with java

Tags: java, pdf, xps

Could you please help me to find a way to convert the `PDF` file to `XPS` file with java programmable? Is it possible to do that as freeware library??

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: sorry, my mistake, of course I mean XPS format

Comment: In future, please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before adding them to a post.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the best solution but according to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsxps/thread/1917fede-bf5c-4c66-92cd-e97cfa0206cc) you can use ghostscript (invoking command line command) to convert the PDF to Images, from those images then create an XPS document:

```
gswin32c.exe -Z, -sDEVICE=png16m-sOutputFile="%04do.png" "temp.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I already checked it, my second problem is, this conversion runs on a IBM machine, i don't want to install ghostscript